# Viewport.unproject() returning NaN (not a number)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to get touch coordinates in world units so that I can draw textures on the screen by using viewport.unproject(Vector3) but it is returning NaN.

My viewport and camera are istantiated as following:

```
public class GameRenderer {

    private InvadersGame game;

    private Viewport viewport;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> shipAnimation;
    private TextureRegion currentShipFrame;
    private Ship ship;
    private CameraDebug cameraDebug;
    private DebugCameraConfig debugCameraConfig;

    private TextureAtlas shipAtlas;

    private float timeElapsed;

    public GameRenderer(InvadersGame game) {
        this.game = game;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(GameConfig.WORLD_WIDTH, GameConfig.WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        shipAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal(AssetPaths.shipAnimation));
        shipAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1/10f, shipAtlas.findRegions("ship"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
        ship = new Ship();
        cameraDebug = new CameraDebug();
        debugCameraConfig = new DebugCameraConfig();
    }

. . .
```

I have a GameScreen class which implements screen and has an instance of GameRenderer, thus calling the init() method.

Here's what I have tried:

```
Public class GameController

. . .

 private void updateShip() {
        ship.setPositions(renderer.getViewport().unproject(ship.getTouchPos()));
        log.debug(Float.toString(renderer.getViewport().unproject(ship.getTouchPos()).x));
    }

. . .
```

where ship.getTouchPos returns a Vector3 of Gdx.input.getX() and y.

Obviously I have an instance of GameRenderer in GameController to get the viewport and use it to convert touch coords to world coords.

log.debug output:

```
I/chatty: uid=10133(com.mygdx.game) GLThread 342 identical 2 lines
D/GameController: NaN
D/GameController: NaN
```

Comment: How is your Viewport set up? It looks like there's a bug in LibGDX's camera that would return NaN if your camera has width or height of 1.

Comment: I think unproject uses a Vector3 and getTouchPos() returns a Vector2 so you may have to convert to a Vector3

Comment: No, there's an overloaded Vector2 version.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have edited my question accordingly

Comment: And is your `WORLD_WIDTH` or `WORLD_HEIGHT` equal to one?

Comment: @Tenfour04 world width = 130f, world height = 216f